# CheckBox's onCheckedChanged not called after programatically changing checked state?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

In my code I `setOnCheckedChangeListener` prior to setting initial value to `CheckBox` but the listener method not called after setting the initial value :

```
final CheckBox check_box = convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

check_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 

// Some logic 
}
}
```

After above line, I set the initial value to CheckBox as follows,

```
if (isConditionTrue) {
            check_box.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            check_box.setChecked(false);
        }
}
```

But the listener method `onCheckedChanged` never called when programmatically changed the check value using method `setChecked()`, but when the user changes it via display it is called. Is this normal behavior or I have implemented it wrongly?

Comment: What is the initial state of your Checkbox? Checked on unchecked? And what is the value of `isConditionTrue`?

Comment: Try changing it from checked to selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setOnCheckedChangeListener()` is called when the checked state of this button changes. However looking at your code, it looks like state of the checkbox might not be changing.

```
if (isConditionTrue) {
            check_box.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            check_box.;
        }
}
```

If `isConditionTrue` is false and check_box is already un-checked, then `setChecked(false)` won't result in invocation of `setOnCheckedChangeListener` won't be called. Same applies for check_box already checked and you try to `setChecked(true);`

Comment: your suggestion seems true thanks its default state is unchecked & I set it setChecked(false) which caused it not to invoke the listener method, Thanks :)

Comment: @pcj great! Enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its normal behavior. Because the listener is attached  to the checkbox, When you change it on the application ui it will call. But if you change it programmatically, it will not execute.